# Can you update WhatsApp's link previews?

Tags: hyperlink, preview, whatsapp

If you share a link in WhatsApp, it gives a preview, which remains the same even after you update the link externally, for example a YouTube video link.

Is there a way to force WhatsApp to refresh this preview?

This question is regardless of the device you use (Desktop, Mobile, etc.).

Kind of like **Scrape Again** in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ :

[image: Facebook's Scrape Again]

Answer (score 6):

I've found that adding random text to the end of the hyperlink clears the cache. so: https://yoursite.com/?876564
Also, make sure you have flushed your site cache before.

Comment: What do you mean flushed your site cache before? We're talking about sharing a link from a random site.

Comment: @LWC No we are not talking about sharing from random sites. We are talking about sharing your own links that you have updated and you want to update the preview snippet on WhatsApp as well. The proposed solution here is the correct answer, append a random query string to the URL to force WhatApp to scrape again.

Comment: Cool, but since the question wasn't about self links, if one must flush then it solves a rather particular case of a general question.

Comment: This was perfect - also, after pasting the new link with the random text, I was able to delete character by characer to the original link with the cache refreshing at every change.

Comment: @OdedBenDov not works now

Comment: This solution is smart. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

Found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49021595/165358):

Removing the `http://` or `https://` from the link will disable
the Whatsapp rich-link previews:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my question was how to make sure the preview is up to date, not how to remove it altogether.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: That's the best answer I can give. There's no way to have a dynamic preview because of the way that Whatsapp works: The sender constructs the entire message (with the preview) and sends it as rich text. The text then goes into the recipient's chat as-is, as a local copy that is no longer related to the original and that can no longer be modified (only deleted). To have the preview re-generated, the message needs to be resent, because it's the sender that creates it.

Comment: The question author is not asking for a dynamic preview, I believe. The question is about how to make WhatsApp fetch data again and create fresh previews for the **subsequent** messages.

Comment: @AKd: This post is not new, and even so, WhatsApp has since changed greatly, so all answers need to be re-verified.